# Can Sonar pull code from my git repository and analyze periodically?

Tags: javascript, code-analysis, sonarqube, static-code-analysis, sonar-runner

I have my source repository hosted in GitHub. I now want my Sonar instance (deployed on Amazon EC2) to pull from the git repository periodically to analyze the codebase. The project is a simple JavaScript project, I do not want ANT, Maven or Jenkins to be involved, but just Sonar to pull code periodically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sonar has no built-on cron, nor any connector to SCM tools to retrieve source code. So retrieving sources and triggering an analysis is out of its scope: this is the responsibility of other tools like CI servers (Jenkins / Hudson / Team City / Bamboo / ...).

Comment: thanks.. after some searching I'm now falling back to Jenkins as an intermediary.

Comment: You could also write a UNIX cron that pulls code from GitHub and launches Maven or Sonar Runner, but using Jenkins is far easier IMO.